# Code assigned to a button on different sheet uses incorrect range

Tags: excel, vba

The below macro copies and pastes ranges on the 'Master Sheet' to elsewhere on the sheet:

```vb
Sub Macro2()
With Worksheets("Master Sheet")
    Range("CC25:CE33").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("CC44").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("CC21").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("CC40").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("CC6:CE14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("CC25").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("CC2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("CC21").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With 
End Sub
```

When I assign it to a button on a different sheet ('Summary_QC') it uses ranges on the 'Summary_QC' sheet rather than the 'Master Sheet', despite stating `With Worksheets("Master Sheet")`.

Comment: You have a `With` statement, but then are not using it on your `Range` objects.... use `.Range` to make it use the `With` instead of the `ActiveSheet`

Comment: Also, think about using other ways of copying data. Select/Copy/Paste is slow and prone to errors, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999/1490783 for alternatives.

Comment: @braX Thank you but I had tried this before and it returns an error - 'select method of range class failed'?

Comment: If you have the right worksheet name, are you sure it's referencing the correct workbook too?

Answer (score 0):

To add the button;

1. Go to the sheet you want to put it in
2. On the top go to Developer tab and click on Insert under the Controls
3. Select Button from Form Control, it will popup Macro selection
4. Select Macro2

---

```
Sub Macro2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, wsCopyTo As Worksheet

Set wsMaster = wb.Sheets("Master Sheet")

wsMaster.Activate

wsMaster.Range("CC25:CE33").Copy
wsCopyTo.Range("CC44").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

wsMaster.Range("CC21").Copy
wsCopyTo.Range("CC40").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
wsMaster.Range("CC6:CE14").Copy
wsCopyTo.Range("CC25").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

wsMaster.Range("CC2").Copy
wsCopyTo.Range("CC21").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

wb.Sheets("Summary_QC").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Vetuka. I should have been more specific. The button is to be on the 'Summary_QC' sheet, but the copy and pasting is to take place all on the 'Master Sheet'. Rather than copying from 'Master Sheet' to 'Summary_QC sheet which I see you code does

Comment: @tthom I updated my answer. This should work like you wanted now. You can also test the code when you run it from Summary_QC sheet.

Answer (score 0):

add this at the beginning of the code before (with):
Worksheets("Master Sheet").activate

and add this at the end of the code before (end sub):
Worksheets("Summary_QC").activate

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### Using the With Statement

- *ThisWorkbook* refers to the workbook containing this code.
- Note the dots at the beginning of each line in the *With* statement: they are 'telling' VBA that the ranges are located on the `Master Sheet` worksheet.
- You don't have to *select* anything.
- The removed *PasteSpecial* parameters were the default values so you don't need them.

```vb
Sub Macro2()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Sheet")
        .Range("CC25:CE33").Copy
        .Range("CC44").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        .Range("CC21").Copy
        .Range("CC40").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        .Range("CC6:CE14").Copy
        .Range("CC25").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        .Range("CC2").Copy
        .Range("CC21").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```